# Can I upload multiple node.js apps under one domain?

Tags: node.js

I use DreamHost as my provider, and I have a VPS plan, allowing me to upload nodejs apps. However I wish to be able to have multiple small apps under one domain, for example

```
www.example.com/app1
www.example.com/app2
www.example.com/app3
```

Is this possible with Node.js?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cant run multiple apps on a single port.
But we can run apps on different port and redirect the url to correct app using nginx e.g

```
server {
  listen 80;
  root /var/www;
  server_name www.example.com;

location /app1 {
    proxy_pass http://localhost:{port}; // app1 server Comment 1
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
}

location /app2 {
    proxy_pass http://localhost:{port};  // app2 server Comment 2
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
}
}
```

This will redirect www.example.com/app1 to app1 server and www.example.com/app2 to app2 server. See comment 1 and 2.

Answer (score 0):

You can't run multiple apps on single port but you can run them on different ports and can access them using those ports like

`www.example.com //app1 (default http port is 80 and default https port is 443 hence you don't need to specify port for the apps using port 80)
www.example.com:3000 //app2`